# Linker - Module machine type conflict

Tags: c++, c, dll, linker, poco

I am trying to use the C++ POCO library in an existing Windows CE solution using Visual Studio 2008. The solution consists of a Windows Forms C# project and a C/C++ native DLL.

I have built the POCO .lib files with the provided .bat build scripts, added them to my DLL project, and everything compiles fine, except that I can't link :

```
PocoFoundationd.lib(PocoFoundationd.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'THUMB'
```

The module machine type of my projet is set to : "Not set".

I don't understand what this is due to. Can this be related to how the POCO .lib files were compiled ? I also don't understand why the error message says : `PocoFoundationd.lib(PocoFoundationd.dll)` while I'm embedding the POCO .lib files into a static compilation, i.e I'm not using a DLL for the POCO library. THe only DLL is the one I'm trying to link.

I have a very limited knownledge of what happens below the C/C++ code, but isn't the code contained in .lib files machine-independant ?

**EDIT**: If I se the machine type to ARM in my project, then the conflict disappears but I get a new one with one of Windows API libs :

```
ws2.lib(WS2.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'THUMB' conflicts with target machine type 'ARM'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to get this to work.

I could open the Visual Studio projects initially provided with the library and recompile the .lib files with the right target machine type.

Initially I couldn't do that because I didn't have installed on my development machine the only SDK in used by the solution, but they explain on the website that one has to manually edit the project and solution files to replace the default platform name by the one to be used.

So in the end, **the DLL configurations of the provided projects have to be compiled with the right target machine type, even if the DLL are not being used**, so that the .lib can be linked in the final project.